# Android: how to force EditText autocorrection?

Tags: android, input, android-edittext, autocorrect

When text correction is enabled on the device, text is corrected after user presses space key.
However if user doesn't add space after the last word, that word is not corrected.
I need to auto correct the last word before sending it.

Any ideas how to do that?

Tried these methods:

1. `input.setText(input.getText() + " ");`
2. `input.setSelection(0, 0)`
3. `KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE); inputMethodManager.dispatchKeyEventFromInputMethod(input, event);`
4. `inputMethodManager.updateSelection(input,0, textLength, 0, textLength);`
5. `Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation(); inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE);`
6. `InputConnection con = input.onCreateInputConnection(new EditorInfo()); con.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE)); con.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE));`

None of the above triggers autocorrection.

Comment: "text is corrected after user presses space key" -- I would not assume that this is an OS-level thing. There are dozens of input method editors that come pre-installed across the 26,000+ Android device models, and many more that people can install from the Play Store or elsewhere. None have to offer auto-correct. AFAIK none that do have to use a space as a trigger to apply auto-correct. "I need to auto correct the last word before sending it" -- why do you think that the user wants that auto-correction? After all, auto-correction is frequently wrong.

Comment: @CommonsWare, This input is needed for fast chatting and this feature is required.
I'm wondering if there is any way to trigger autocorrection of the input method (if applicable).